# iCloud - How to save archive containing array of custom objects

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud, archiving, custom-object

I have developed a small app that stores locally in iOS through archiving an array of custom objects containing:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString    *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString    *dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString    *desc;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString    *url;
```

I want to sync said archive using iCloud and I believe the recommended mechanism is through a UIDocument subclass.
All UIDocument examples I found utlilized a single instance with 1 single NSString, so I am a little confused how to go about syncing a whole array of custom objects but utilizing UIDocument (like I do today locally through NSCoding).

Should I create an array of UIDocument objects containing the properties listed above, should I create an instance of UIDocument containing 1 instance of the data object described above and then create an array containing all the instances, or should 1 single UIDocument contain the complete array of custom objects ?

I have done some research but I am still confused.
In the end I would need to sync just 1 file containing an array of said custom objects.

Thanks in advance for your help

What I have today is a custom class as described above with 4 strings called Snippet and in my Root view Controller I have an NSMutableArray called list where I add each new instance of that Snippet Class.

```
self.list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Snippet *newEntry = [[Snippet alloc] init];
[self.list addObject:newEntry];
```

Should I create an UI Document subclass that owns the array of custom objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/CreateCustomDocument/CreateCustomDocument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH8-SW1) does indeed show a UIDocument subclass that just has one string, but it returns a NSData from `-contentsForType:error:`. You can store as many objects as you like in an NSData using an NSKeyedArchiver. Read [Serializing Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/serializing.html) to learn how to encode objects using NSKeyedArchiver (and keep reading to learn how to get them back!).

Using your properties as an example...

```
@interface MyDocument : UIDocument
{
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString    *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString    *dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString    *desc;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString    *url;
@end

@implementation MyDocument

//...

- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [archiver encodeObject:dateCreated forKey:@"created"];
    [archiver encodeObject:desc forKey:@"desc"];
    [archiver encodeObject:url forKey:@"url"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    // release archiver if you're not using ARC
    return data;
}
@end;
```

WARNING: I haven't compiled the code above, so no guarantees. This should serve as an example to illustrate using an archiver to store multiple objects in a single data object which you can return as your document's content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I understood you correctly I could use + (NSData *)archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)rootObject with the array and then - (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError archiving the whole array in 1 single instance of UIDocument

Comment: How would you declare the UIDocument in that case ?

Comment: I don't see what array you're talking about. I'll add a snippet above to try to help.

Comment: I added to clarify what I meant about the array

Comment: If you want to add an array to the mix, you can use `-encodeObject:forKey:` just as you do for strings. Just make sure that all the objects in the array implement NSCoding. You really ought to read the *Archives and Serializations Programming Guide* -- this is all explained there.